# What is the meaning of the construction « s’ennuyer à faire qch »?

Tags: verbes, constructions

On [Académie Française](http://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9E1713) the sentence « Je me suis ennuyé à lire ce livre. » is written. I would like to know the meaning of this sentence and more importantly I’ve been trying to find out if the construction « s’ennuyer à infinitive » exists and the meaning of that construction. I’ve checked [Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/ennuyer), [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s_ennuyer/29685), [Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/ennuyer), [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/s-ennuyer) and [CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ennuyer) but I couldn’t find anything.

Thus please could you guys tell me

(1) the meaning of « Je me suis ennuyé à lire ce livre. »

(2) if the construction « s’ennuyer à faire qch » exists and its’ meaning and please could you provide your source

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ennuyer

Comment: @Personne Thank you for this link but I’ve already checked this out (though I forgot to mention it) but I can’t seem to find the answers to my two questions via CNRTL. :/

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr → portail lexical → lexicographie

Comment: … et vous analysez tous les exemples

Answer (score 2):

The construction ***s’ennuyer à*** + infinitive does exist, if only because there are sentences using it in dictionaries.

There are two cases. The first and more common one is ***s'ennuyer à mourir*** and the likes (*à crever, à périr...*) Here the complement is just there to emphasize the fact something was boring.

It is very similar to the English "**I was bored to death**".

In the second case, the complement is not there to emphasize but to state what was, depending on the context, boring or annoying to you.

> ***Je me suis ennuyé à lire ce livre***

means either:

> I read that book and **it was a boring experience**

or:

> I read that book and **it was an annoying experience**.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. (1) So it’s correct to say « Je m’ennuie faire qch. » means “ I’m doing sth but it’s boring.”?

Comment: It would be incorrect without the preposition. What would be correct is *Je m'ennuie **à** faire quelque chose*.

Comment: De nos jours, "s'ennuyer à faire quelque chose" me semble beaucoup moins courant que "s'ennuyer en faisant quelque chose". Au premier abord je l'aurais même bien rapproché d'un "s'embêter à faire quelque chose", au sens *prendre la peine de faire quelque chose qui nous déplaît*, mais c'est peut-être un peu osé.

Comment: @XouDo Non, au contraire, je ne trouve pas le rapprochement osé. C'est même pour ça que dans ma réponse, j'ai distingué les deux sens (*boring* et *annoying*) qu'a *ennuyer*. Les verbe *embêter* et *emmerder* ont la même dualité. (*Je m'emmerde* a en général le premier, *Tu m'emmerdes* en général le deuxième).